# How to get default input in a WP7 TextBox while there is no user input?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I show some default input while there is no user input?

I mean when I want to add e.g. a new appointment in the calender I see
"Subject" and "Location" in grey letters. When i click on it, they go away and i see the user input.

How to make this in my own app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `textbox` control you can use the `GotFocus` event to remove the text(which you can define initially) and change the `Foreground` to `App.Resources["PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush` from the code behind.

```
<TextBox FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontSize="{StaticResource 
PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"  x:Name="textBox" GotFocus="myHandler_GotFocus"
Text="Enter some text.." Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" />
```

In code behind

```
private void myHandler_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){ this.textBox.Text = ""; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WatermarkedTextBox-custom-control